# How do I get an image from TMDB API

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app on android studio where I populate cards that swipe left and right with movie name and image. The name appears on the card no problem, but when I use glide to add in the URL ("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/") before the image name ("poster_path") I get the error

"You cannot start a load on a not yet attached View or a Fragment where getActivity() returns null (which usually occurs when getActivity() is called before the Fragment is attached or after the Fragment is destroyed)"

Is this because of glide? Is there another way to do this without glide? I am not using a recycler view to populate the cards I am using a library I found on github. I am also using a Json URL.

Here is my Adapter class

```
package com.project300.movieswipe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<MovieModelClass> objects;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<MovieModelClass> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        MovieModelClass movies = (MovieModelClass) getItem(position);

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

       ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        Glide.with(context)
            .load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/"+ objects.get(position).getImg())
            .into(img);


        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

        name.setText(movies.getName());

        return convertView ;

    }

}
```

and the main activity

```
 public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String current = "";

            try {
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

                try {

                    url = new URL(JSON_URL);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

                    int data = isr.read();
                    while (data != -1) {
                        current += (char) data;
                        data = isr.read();
                    }

                    return current;

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    ;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (urlConnection != null) {
                        //  urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return current;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {


            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");


                movieList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    MovieModelClass model = new MovieModelClass();

                    
                    model.setName(jsonObject1.getString("title"));
                    model.setImg(jsonObject1.getString("poster_path"));

                 

                    movieList.add(model);
                }


                adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, movieList);
                flingContainer.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
```

model class

```
package com.project300.movieswipe;

import android.media.Image;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MovieModelClass {

    String name;
   String img;

    public MovieModelClass(String name, String img) {
        this.name = name;
        this.img = img;
    }
    public MovieModelClass() {

    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        this.img = img;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getImg() {
       return img;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because your context inside **MyAdapter** is null, so you need to set your context based on your constructor like this:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<MovieModelClass> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = objects;
}
```